# Approach in developing a Hotel reservation system

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

I've designed the whole skeleton of the application.

But I need real help with the room reservations.

The application should work like this:
I have 10 rooms in the system.
I choose dates for booking from 26.04.2013 until 01.05.2013
I only want to be able to choose the rooms that are available for this dates, the ones that are occupied should be invisible or not being able to choose.

I have absolutely no idea how should I go about solving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: a software algorithm?

Comment: There's quite some difference between an algorithm and designing an entire piece of software. If you ran into a specific issue with programming, we'll gladly help.

Comment: I'm not retarded, thank you.
I don't think this is an entire piece of software, this is a part of the software which as I said I have no idea how to approach.

Comment: I did Hotel systems before, ping me on Skype - there are  few finer points beside the algorithm

Comment: Wow great! How do I find you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know what you're trying to get at. Perhaps your question just needs to be rephrased. Let's assume your list of rooms is a combo box. So you want the `selectItems` to only include available rooms. So you might create an empty `ArrayList`, then loop through all the rooms and, for each, do a full text search to find any reservations where the dates overlap the dates you're trying to book. If the result count is 0, add the room to the `ArrayList`. When you've finished searching against all rooms, return the list. This approach will be equally valid if your list of available rooms is a repeat control... you'd just use the same algorithm to calculate the `value` attribute instead of `selectItems`.

Comment: This is an actually smart answer, unlike the people here that think it's more important to teach me a lesson on what to ask.

Ok so, i was thinking of creating a weirdly big "if" function to see which rooms are available for the chosen dates.
Also, Formula and Lotus Script are not my best side so, is there a better way to achieve this, better than 10 nested ifs?

Comment: If this is an XPage, as the tag on the question indicates, then the best language to use is Java. If you're not comfortable with Java, SSJS. The approach described in my answer would not be nested `if`s, it would be a single `for` with an `if` inside it. The `for` would be a loop through all the possible rooms. Inside that loop, you'd construct a FT search query for each room (i.e. `[Form] CONTAINS room AND [StartDate]...`. The `if` would simply check whether there are any matches for that room... if there are, it's unavailable for those dates.